# Django - accessing a project prom another project

Tags: django, import, project

I've built a little project in Django- a rol web, with a user system and etc.

Now I want to host it under my personal web, which is another Django project with info about myself.

Is there any way to "import" the rol project in order to access it with a button from my personal web?

If that's so, how efficient would it be? Could I add a "personal projects"-portfolio like tabs with urls leading to different projects, all stored under then same project?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to add it as an app inside your first Django project which contains your personal information?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: no, you cannot "import" a django project as part of another django project - not without a lot of pain, dirty hacks and unexpected breakages at least. Django has not been designed to be used that way.

You can of course reuse apps (assuming they've been developped with reusability in mind) from one project into another one, but you'll still have to (re)do all the project-level integration.

Another solution is to deploy those "side projects" under subdomains of your main site, ie if your main site is 'xbro.com', you could deploy your 'rol' project under `rol.xbro.com` (just plain ordinary django project deployment using vhosts), and add links between the two projects where you see fit (hard-coded in your base templates, managed by some specific "menu" or "mini-cms" app, etc). You can still share the database (or part of it) for user accounts or other common resources if needed (you might have to properly configure session cookie so they're shared between projects though).